# How to constantly update variable in Python and use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to code a trading bot using Python.
I have a list of yesterday's stock prices and a function which changes this list ( so I need to run it daily).
I also have second function which I need to run every minute and which takes the list from above as an argument.
How do I make this work so that both functions run periodically, but do not run first function each time I run the second function?

```
list_prices = [...]
def function1():
    global list_prices
    list_prices = ...
    return
def function2(list_prices):
    ...
    return
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to ask. The natural arrangement would be to check if 24 hours have passed, then run the update function before the regular function you run frequently. You are in complete control here; Python will not run any function unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly but does this answer it?
Running function2 every 60 sec, function1 every 24 hours

```py
from time import time

last_run_function1 = 0
while True:
    now = time()
    time_delta = now - last_run_function1
    if time_delta >= 60 * 60 * 24:  # 60 sec * 60 min * 24 hours
        function1()
        last_run_function1 = time()
    function2(list_prices)
    time.sleep(60)
```